# Java openStream() working time depends on web site code?

Tags: java, html, time

I have done today a test and my results are strange. I used code below and test some of web pages.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
URL url = new URL("http://wp.pl");
System.out.println("" + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000);
start = System.nanoTime();
InputStream is = url.openStream();
System.out.println("" + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000);

start = System.nanoTime();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("" + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000);

start = System.nanoTime();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
System.out.println("" + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000);
//After this point reading whole site goes nice and fast
```

Only second time was diffrent (the rest was arround 0). Here are the times for different sites of (url.openStream()):

adress | time | lines of code
yahoo.com/          1000 943 
bbc.com             230  1500
news.google.pl/     138  384
free-ebooks.net     776  668 
wp.pl               3066 2811

The point is the time is different and its look like it depends on length of site code. My question:
Do url.openStream() download whole site code? It should not just open stream and wait for user to read it?

Comment: Your code doesn't show if you measured the actual time of reading (only the construction of the `BufferedReader`). Did you measure that as well? If so, what did you find there?

Comment: *"..w8 for user to read it?"*  Given these are international forums, I'd spell words properly rather than *wait* for people to understand 'text message' spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openStream` waits *at least* until the server starts sending the response. Otherwise it couldn't know if it can actually return an `InputStream` or should throw an exception instead.

On many webservers the actual sending of data is the shortest time: by the time the web server has decided which headers to send (and thus starts sending the response) it already knows the full content.

Comment: IS there any way of faster reading URL content (only first 20 lines)?

Comment: I doubt that using another mechanism will be significantly faster, because the slowing factor is probably the network communication and *not* pure CPU time.